# Getting TypeError when iterating over an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Rails, and I am getting an error in my jQuery code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The actual code where I am getting the error:

```js
// args is for internal usage only
    each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
        var value,
            i = 0,
            length = obj.length,
            isArray = isArraylike( obj );

        if ( args ) {
            if ( isArray ) {
                for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                    value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                    if ( value === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for ( i in obj ) {
                    value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                    if ( value === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: where is the code where you clicked?

Comment: are you trying to bind an event in loop?

Comment: the code i have shared is the code snippet from the jquery file

Comment: i got error in the console and when i clicked the error , it opened the jquery file and the code snippet which i have given in the question , 
i am using the jquery gem in rails

Comment: You have $.each(...) inside click handler?

Comment: That's fine but can you post that code which you tried to run and that caused this error?

Comment: see rails included this jquery file by itself, i am not using any code 
and this file is included everywhere in the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about try this?

```
var length = Object.keys(obj).length
```

**or**

```
var length = 0;
for (var o in obj) {
    length++;
}
```